# What this means: "that is very nuanced"

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Does "very nuanced" mean "very different" in this sentence?

> We are marrying the two up in a way that is very nuanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

## Nuance

> : a subtle difference in or shade of meaning, expression, or sound.

<sup><sup>Source: **https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nuance**</sup></sup>

---

The definition of "*nuance*" is a subtle difference. An example of "*nuance*" is the difference between light lime green and lime green.

"*Subtle*" in this context means,

> So slight as to be difficult to detect or describe; elusive: a subtle smile.

OR

> Not immediately obvious or comprehensible.

<sup><sup>Source: **https://www.thefreedictionary.com/subtle**</sup></sup>

Comment: Merci for clarifying this up.

Comment: @sci9 - I'm glad it helped you :)

Comment: And a little question, Could we replace "that is very nuanced" with "that is not obvious "? @Justin

Comment: @sci9 - Yes, you can.

Comment: Merci beaucoup +1.